# Why won't all of my rectangles fit in my custom UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgrect

I have a UIView named `gameView` which the trailing, leading, top, and bottom space are constrained to the `Superview`.

I programmatically create 5 UIViews (filled in rectangles) and make `gameView` my `referenceView` with which I will do some dynamic animations later on.

I want the 5 rectangles spread evenly and to have some spacing in between. Let's set spacing to be `CGFloat = 8`

Here's how I tried to fit all the rectangles in the UIView:

When I `println(gameView.bounds.size.width)`, Swift says that the width is `600`.

Because I want spacing in between each rectangle, and spacing from the left and right sides, the total amount of available space for the rectangles is 600 - (number of rectangles + 1) * (spacing), which would equal 600-(6*8) = 552.

Now to find the width for each of the 5 rectangles. I did 552 / 5 = 110.4

So according to my method, each rectangle should be 110.4 in width.

However, when I add the rectangles in another method, it barely fits 3 rectangles.

Is my math incorrect, or is there something major I'm not considering? Even setting the spacing between rectangles to 1 which is essentially nothing doesn't make a difference.

I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    animator.addBehavior(breakOutBehavior)
    createAndPlaceBricks()
}


var brickSize: CGSize {
    //finds a correct sized rectangle based on a few constants
    return findAppropriateWidthAndHeightForBrick(ConstantsForDistances.distanceBetweenXBricks, ySpacing: ConstantsForDistances.distanceBetweenYBricks, bricksPerRow: ConstantsForDistances.bricksPerRow, numberOfRows: ConstantsForDistances.numberOfRows)
}
```

Here is the function to find the width:

```
private func findAppropriateWidthAndHeightForBrick(xSpacing: CGFloat, ySpacing: CGFloat, bricksPerRow: Int, numberOfRows: Int) -> CGSize {
    let availableWidth = gameView.bounds.size.width - (xSpacing * CGFloat(bricksPerRow + 1))
    let sizeForBricks = availableWidth / CGFloat(bricksPerRow)
    let heightSize = sizeForBricks / 4   
    return CGSize(width: sizeForBricks, height: heightSize)
}
```

And here is the function which creates the UIViews (although I'm 90% sure the error is not in here)

```
func createAndPlaceBricks() {
    for eachXBrick in 0..<ConstantsForDistances.bricksPerRow {
        for eachYBrick in 0..<ConstantsForDistances.numberOfRows {
            var frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: brickSize)
            frame.origin.y = CGFloat(ConstantsForDistances.distanceBetweenYBricks + brickSize.height * CGFloat(eachYBrick) + ConstantsForDistances.distanceBetweenYBricks * CGFloat(eachYBrick))
            frame.origin.x = CGFloat(ConstantsForDistances.distanceBetweenXBricks + brickSize.width * CGFloat(eachXBrick) + ConstantsForDistances.distanceBetweenXBricks * CGFloat(eachXBrick))
            let brickView = UIView(frame: frame)
            brickView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            //add rectangle here
            breakOutBehavior.addBrick(brickView)
        }
    }
}
```

In my breakOutBehavior class I have the following:

```
func addBrick(brick: UIView) {
    dynamicAnimator?.referenceView?.addSubview(brick)
}
```

Comment: The value 600 width looks like it's the width from a universal Storyboard scene. Where do you add the rectangles? And are you running on iPad or iPhone?

Comment: See the edit I made, I add the rectangle with `breakOutBehavior.addBrick(brickView)` and I am running on an iPhone.

Comment: No, I mean where you you call this method (`awakeFromNib`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`...) . Non of the iPhones has a width of 600 points. So you are reading the width before the view put onto the screen.

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the response! I call createAndPlaceBricks() in viewDidLoad. 

And I call findAppropriateWidthAndHeightForBrick(...) from the brickSize variable

Comment: Try to call it in `viewDidLayout()`. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/viewDidLayout

Comment: That fixed the issue. I was pulling my hair out, thank you